# Can't opening alert/Dialog box after clicking gcm notifications in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented Google Cloud Messaging in my phonegap app, but i have to display a message in dialog box or alert box after clicking the gcm notification in status bar. I have googled it but could't work anything. 
GCMIntentService.java

```
    @Override
public void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnregistered - regId: " + regId);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(final Context arg0, final Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
    Log.i("Registration", arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
    String message = arg1.getStringExtra("message");

    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), message);
}

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.tbgicon, message, when);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, KBJphoneGAP.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    String title = "The Business Game";
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Here is My MainActivity.java in phonegap

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    // super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 11000);
}
```

Please anybody help me about this, I have tried with alertdialog box in onMessage method but after receiving notification application is stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code :

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, KBJphoneGAP.class);
```

Clicking on the notification will open the `KBJphoneGAP` activity.
I'm not familiar with PhoneGap (I only know native Android development), so I'm not sure what that activity is.

If you want to open a different activity, change that line.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes we can open Android activity with intent and there we can display alertdialog but in the phonegap i am not sure weather we can call another android activity or not. I have tried this but couldn't work.